# Is there a real number exceeds cube by $1$

Tags: polynomials

I tried to make up an equation :

$x-x^3 = 1\implies x(1-x)(1+x)=1$

<del>Get $x=1, x=-1$. For each of the two values: $x=1$ (double roots), & $x=-1$, could not find satisfying this property.</del>

<del>Am confused, and am not sure if this is the way to disprove the title.</del>

Comment: The arrow $x(1-x)(1+x)=1\implies x=1, x=-1$ surely is false.

Comment: graph $y=x^3$ and $y=x-1$, you'll see that the only intersection point has negative $x$

Comment: You *can* write the solution in closed form using the known formula, but it's not pretty.

Comment: Note that $1-1^3=0$ and $(-1)-(-1)^3 = 0$, so your algebra is very flawed.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-x%5E3%3D1

Comment: No, the question is just fine. Your algebraic deduction is flawed. The intermediate value theorem will, in fact, tell you that $f(x)=x-x^3-1$ has a solution. Indeed, every real cubic equation has a root.

Comment: @Mason I do not still know how the real solution was arrived at. Please help.

Comment: @TedShifrin Please elaborate your last comment, or please make an answer out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.If $x(1-x)(1+x) = 1$, then it *does not imply* that $x = 1 , x=-1$ etc. In fact, it implies that $x$ *cannot be equal* to $1,-1$ or $0$. This is because in each of these cases the left hand side is zero, when it is supposed to be equal to one, which is the right hand side.

When the product of some numbers is zero, then at least one of them is zero. This allows us, for example when $(x-2)(x-3) = 0$, to conclude that $x=2$ or $x=3$.

However, when the product of some numbers is $1$, then *nothing can be concluded about the precise value of any of the quantities*. At most, you can conclude that all the terms are non-zero, so that *prohibits* some values of $x$, like how I prohibited above, but that still leaves you a large set of values with which to work.

Given the equation $x - x^3 = 1$, this is a cubic equation, so it can be solved by Cardano's general method for cubics. However, it turns out that $x^3-x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial (in integers) so you cannot obtain any factorization here.

What you can do, is find the location of this real root using the intermediate value theorem, (a case of) which says that if $f(x) = x^3 - x+1$ and you find two numbers $ a < b$ such that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite signs, then there is a real root of $f$ between $a$ and $b$. Using this, we can assert the existence of a root between $-1$ and $-2$, for example, since $f(-1) = 1$ while $f(-2) = -5$, so they have differing signs.

Comment: I hope using the intermediate value theorem, you concluded that the given cubic equation is an irreducible one in the domain of integers, as the root lies between $x=-1$ & $x=-2$.

Comment: I concluded irreducibility (of a *cubic* polynomial, which is why this suffices) using the rational root theorem, which says that if $\frac pq$ is a rational root of the polynomial $f(x)$, then $p$ is a factor of the constant term of $f$ and $q$ is a factor of the leading term. Given that the constant and leading terms are $1$ and $-1$ respectively, you do not have many choices for $p,q$ (how many factors of $1$ and $-1$ are there?), and none of them work, by substituting in $f(x)$. So the real root of $f(x)$ (if any) is irrational, and you can locate it more precisely using the IVT.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $f(x)=x-x^3-1(x \in \mathbb{R}).$ We want to find the real roots for the equation $f(x)=0$.

Notice that $f'(x)=1-3x^2.$ Thus, we can obtain the local extremum points are $$x_1=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3},x_2=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}.$$ Based on these, we can draw the graphic of $y=f(x)$ as follows

[image]

Thus, you can see there exists only one solution for $f(x)=0$, which is located between $-2$ and $-1$.

## Reply

About the principle of graphing, I give an example.

You have seen that $f'\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)=0$, and $f'(x)<0$ for $x<-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$. Thus, you may know that $f(x)$ decreases with an increasing $x$,where $x \leq -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}.$ Now,you can draw a descending curve over $\left(-\infty,-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right).$

How about $-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}<x<\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$? And how about $x>\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$? Can you discuss the sign of $f'(x)$ and graph them?

Comment: Thanks for this novel (at least to me) approach. I am still confused as how this will help in plotting the curve, as shown next: For $f^{′}(x)=0$, the values are $x=±0.577367$. The link between the curve's real root at $x=−1.3247$ and the above two values for zero value of derivative is not clear, as $x=−1.3247$ is lesser than $−0.577367$. I can only add inflexion point to get $f′′(x)=0$, but this yields $0−6x=0⟹x=0$, which does not help but confuses more as there should be two sign change points on the curve as shown in your graph. Not clear how use derivatives (first/second) to plot curve.

Comment: @jiten I reply to you above, Hope to help you.

Comment: For $x\gt \frac{\sqrt{3}}3$, $f^{'}(x)\gt 0$, as $f^{''}(x)=-6x$ is negative. Reverse applies for negative values of $x$. This is indicated by my 1st comment, that states inflection point $x=0$. I am adding a request for the same - i.e., why inflection point tells nothing about the points $x= (f^{'}(x)=0)$.  --- Coming back, in between $x=\pm 0.577367$, there should be change from decreasing to increasing function, with slope $f^{'}(x)$ being positive here.

Comment: you should notice that the stationary point is relevent to the monotonicity,and the inflection point to the concavity. The two are not the same at all.....

Comment: Kindly help by preventing post from deletion, by upvoting it.